# Does gravity cause spacetime to bend?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity

Does gravity cause spacetime to bend even though space has no mass?

Answer (score 1):

It's not Space that bends it's Space-Time that bends. If you think of a trampoline, and you put a bowling ball in the centre. The bowling ball is bending the stretchy trampoline material, and if you put a tennis ball on the trampoline and rolled it round the bowling ball, that's how the Solar System works. The bowling ball is pulling the tennis ball towards it, because it has curved the trampoline (space-time). The bowling is acting as the sun and the tennis ball is acting as the Earth.

It's all to do with Einstein's theory of General Relativity, in which the observed gravitational effect between masses results from their warping of space-time.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the gravity which bends Spacetime, but Spacetime curvature itself is seen as gravity.

In the presence of mass (in general, mass-energy-tensor), geometry of Spacetime is changed. Only talking about plane, in the presence of mass, this Euclidean statement can become invalid: "Parallel lines never intersect each other." I think, you can get idea with this what a Spacetime curvature is.

Now, due to this Spacetime curvature, an object in uniform motion looks like sensing acceleration. This illusion is known as Gravity.